# Special characters in folder names cause delete by batch-file to fail

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, special-characters

I'm trying to delete empty folders via a batch file, in Windows.

> for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir V:\Temp /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"

fails on folders with special characters - specifically parentheses and Alt+(numpad)7 bullets.

How can I process folders with these special characters in their name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I side-stepped this issue by using [DirClean](http://download.cnet.com/DirClean/3000-2248_4-75945101.html). It seems to be no longer developed, and its page has gone dead, but it works just fine.